# Java awt repaint() not calling update(graphics g)

Tags: java, graphics, awt

I have been following the tutorial for "Kilobolt game dev" found here: http://www.kilobolt.com/unit-2-creating-a-game-i.html

The issue I'm currently having is that I have an update() method that according to the tutorial and java's documentation should be called when I call repaint() however it isnt, which is making the frame not render anything at all.

Here is the code in question:

```
 @Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(true){
        ball.update();
        playerpaddle.update();
        computerpaddle.update();

        repaint();
        //System.out.println("s!");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
 @Override
public void update(Graphics g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("update");
    if(background == null){
        background = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        second = background.getGraphics();
    }
    second.setColor(getBackground());
    second.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    second.setColor(getForeground());
    paint(second);

    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
}
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("paint");
    g.drawImage(iball, ball.getXPos(), ball.getYPos(), this);
    g.drawImage(iplayerpaddle, playerpaddle.getXPos(), playerpaddle.getYPos(), this);
    g.drawImage(icomputerpaddle, computerpaddle.getXPos(), computerpaddle.getYPos(), this);
}
```

EDIT:
I am currently on the fourth 'day' according to that tutorial, everything is the same besides the frame code that I had to change because keylistener wasnt working properly.

```
 Frame game = (Frame)this.getParent().getParent();
    game.setSize(Constants.MAX_WIDTH, Constants.MAX_HEIGHT);
    game.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    game.setFocusable(true);
    game.addKeyListener(this);
    game.setTitle("Pong Clone");
```

I've also tried calling update() directly with update(this.getGraphics()) however I still am only getting a white frame that never changes, even after update() and paint() are called.

EDIT2:
I've fixed the background issue I had misread the threading functions and I switched my "gameloop.run()" to "gameloop.start()", this allows me to render the black background however my ball, and paddles will still not render.